# AngularJS: Duplicates in a repeater error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to display an array of objects using ng-repeat and the track by expression but keep getting this error: 
`Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: contact in ctrl.contacts track by contact.id |
                                                        SearchbarFilter:ctrl |
                                                        orderBy:'+firstName' |
                                                        limitTo: 10, Duplicate key: [], Duplicate value: {"id":12,"firstName":"Yoda","lastName":"Greenwise","email":"yoda@republic.com","phone1":"(404) 333-1122","phone2":"(678) 123-4567","company":"Republic","jobTitle":"Jedi Master","address1":"37 Jedi Road","address2":"Suite 173","city":"Jedi Counsil","state":"Coruscant","postalCode":"31234","personType":"Prospect"}`
The ng-repeat looks like this: 
`<div ng-repeat="contact in ctrl.contacts track by contact.id | SearchbarFilter:ctrl | orderBy:'+firstName' | limitTo: 10">`
I have tried using "track by $index" but get the same error.
The array of objects in ctrl.contacts:

```
[
  {
    "id": 10,
    "firstName": "Darth",
    "lastName": "Vader",
    "email": "darthvader@empire.com",
    "phone1": "(404) 987-6543",
    "phone2": "(671) 234-1203",
    "company": "Galatic Empire",
    "jobTitle": "Sith Lord",
    "address1": "20 Death Star Lane",
    "address2": "Royal Suite",
    "city": "Adrift in space",
    "state": "Galaxy",
    "postalCode": "34213",
    "personType": null
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "firstName": "Yoda",
    "lastName": "Greenwise",
    "email": "yoda@republic.com",
    "phone1": "(404) 333-1122",
    "phone2": "(678) 123-4567",
    "company": "Republic",
    "jobTitle": "Jedi Master",
    "address1": "37 Jedi Road",
    "address2": "Suite 173",
    "city": "Jedi Counsil",
    "state": "Coruscant",
    "postalCode": "31234",
    "personType": "Prospect"
  }
]
```

If I just leave out the track by expression, everything renders properly but I need to use the track by expression so I can speed up the amount of time it takes to render the the results whenever the filter updates.  I've tried several possible solutions but nothing seems to work, which leads me to believe there is something wrong with the structure of my array but I could be totally wrong about that, so if some light could be shed on this issue, that would be great!

Comment: What is the result of this expression?
`{{ ctrl.contacts | SearchbarFilter:ctrl | orderBy:'+firstName' | limitTo: 10 }}`

Comment: Please share exact nr-repeat  code part. The code you provided is not valid at all

Comment: @Samir <div class="vertical record" ng-repeat="contact in ctrl.contacts | SearchbarFilter:ctrl | PersonTypeFilter:ctrl | GrowthPlansFilter:ctrl | orderBy:'+firstName' | limitTo: 10"> Could you please explain how this not valid at all?

Comment: Do any of those 9 records have the same id?

Comment: @HankScorpio No they do not.  I would post the entire list but it's too long to put in a comment.  contact.id is unique for each contact object

Comment: Are any filter that you using with ng-repeat creating duplicate record? Have you tried without using your filters? Because I just tried without filters and got fine

Comment: @Samir That was it, somewhere my filters created duplicate records.  Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

After investing if the filters were creating duplicate records I discovered that it was not actually the filters because they were not creating duplicate records, but it was the location of "track by" in the ng-repeat expression.  "track by" has to be the last thing in the expression so instead of:

```
<div class="vertical record" ng-repeat="contact in ctrl.contacts track by contact.id | SearchbarFilter:ctrl | PersonTypeFilter:ctrl | GrowthPlansFilter:ctrl | orderBy:'+firstName' | limitTo: 10">
```

The expression had to be changed to:

```
<div class="vertical record" ng-repeat="contact in ctrl.contacts | SearchbarFilter:ctrl | PersonTypeFilter:ctrl | GrowthPlansFilter:ctrl | orderBy:'+firstName' | limitTo: 10 track by contact.id">
```